# How do you call a function in a function?

Tags: python, function

I have a function and I'm making another one in which I need to call the first function. I don't have experience in Python, but I know that in languages like MATLAB it's possible as long as they're in the same directory.

A basic example:

```
def square(x):
    square = x * x
```

(and saved)

Now in my new function I want to use the function square I tried:

```
def something (y, z)
  import square
  something = square(y) + square(z)
  return something
```

Which displays: `builtins.TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`.

What should I do?

Comment: if its in the same file, you can just call the function

Comment: Just don't import it.  Only modules get imported.  You seem to happen to have a module named `square` which you import, then that overrides the name of the function of the same name.  It is not usual in Python to put each function in its own file (and therefore module).  Just put all your functions in one file (module).  Modules are used only in case you have very large structures which logically do not fit into one thing.

Answer (score 12):

No need for `import` if its in the same file.

Just call `square` from the `something` function.

```
def square(x):
  square = x * x
  return square

def something (y, z)
  something = square(y) + square(z)
  return something
```

More simply:

```
def square(x):
  return x * x

def something (y, z)
  return square(y) + square(z)
```

Answer (score 5):

***If***, and only if, you have the `square` function defined in a `square` module, then you should look to import the simple name from it instead.

```
from square import square
```

If you don't want to change anything, then you need to use its fully qualified name:

```
something = square.square(y) + square.square(z)
```

The module's name is `square`, and you can't call functions on modules.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options.

1. Put everything in one file.  Then you only need to call the other function; forget about all `import`s then.
2. Put the `square` function in a different file, e. g. `foo.py`.  Then your using function needs to `import` it.  For that you have two options again: `import foo` and use `foo.square(y)` or `from foo import square` and use `square(y)`.  (You can name your module like your function as well -- the two have separate name spaces -- so then you would have to `from square import square`.)

Modules (i. e. in a separate file) are used for grouping logically connected things together, e. g. all mathematical functions, all operating-system related things, all random number generator related things, etc.  So in your case which looks like a first test I'd propose to put everything in one file and forget about all `import`s.

Answer (score 2):

2 way to use a function within an other:

1. You define the `square()` function in another `.py` file (`ex: myfile.py`) and then, you can import the function this way:

```py
from myfile import square

def newFunction():
   square()
```

2. You define the function in the same file and then there is no need for the `import` and you can use `square()` directly.