# Using a function within a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, class

So I have a class with some functions. I want to use a function in another function to calculate the fuelconsumption.

I have the attribute self.consumption, which is calculated within the function **`Calculate_consumption`**.

Now I want to write a new function, which is updating the kilometer counter and also calculating if you are driving efficient.

So, I want to calculate the consumption by using the function **`Claculate_consumption`** and then see if it is bigger then 8 or not.

Well I tried to just write the function as I have found it here on Stackoverflow: [How do you call a function in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958704/how-do-you-call-a-function-in-a-function)

But this solution somehow does not work. Maybe somebody can point out my mistake.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, kmDigit):
        self.kmDigit = int(kmDigit)
        self.Max = 8
        self.consumption = 0

    def Claculate_consumption(self, Liter, km):
        self.consumption += (Liter/km)*100
        return round(self.consumption, 2)

    def Refuel(self,Liter, km):
        self.kmDigit += km
        print self.kmDigit
        a = Claculate_consumption(Liter, km)

        if a > self.Max:
            b = self.consumption - self.Max
            print 'Your fuel consumption is too high!'
        else:
            print 'Nice!'
```

I am getting a `**NameError**` in ***line 14***, because `Calculate_consumption` is somehow a `global name`.

Comment: use `a = self.Claculate_consumption(Liter, km)`

Comment: You're misspelling Calculate. Although looks like you have done so consistently so doesn't contribute to an error.

Answer (score 3):

You have to write: `a = self.Claculate_consumption(Liter, km)`
because your program does not know where to look for this method. **Self** says that this method is in the same class in which you call the method

> self : self represents the instance of the class. By using the "self" keyword we can access the attributes and methods of the class in python.
>   [https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-**init**-method-in-python-class/](https://micropyramid.com/blog/understand-self-and-__init__-method-in-python-class/)